# Shorten nested IFs

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have the following code which works perfectly.  However, just looking at it makes me believe there must be a shorter, more elegant way. Switch() is obviously not the answer, so I am stuck with nested if's.

```
if (mode  == 1)
{
   if (distance <= 4000)
   {
       modeValue = "1F";
   }

   else if (distance > 4000 && distance <= 8000)
   {
       modeValue = "2F";
   }

   else if (distance > 8000 && distance <= 12000)
   {
       modeValue = "3F";
   }

   else if (distance > 12000)
   {
       modeValue = "F 0-5";
   }
 }

 else if (mode == 2)
 {
    if (distance <= 500)
    {
        modeValue = "";
    }

    else if (distance > 500 && distance <= 4000)
    {
        modeValue = "2F";
    }

    else if (distance > 4000 && distance <= 8000)
    {
        modeValue = "3F";
    }

    else if (distance > 8000 && distance <= 12000)
    {
        modeValue = "4F";
    }

    else if (distance > 12000)
    {
        modeValue = "F 0-5";
    }
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should try this question on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One way to clean it up is to methodize the whole thing.  Another way of doing things is making distance the property of an object that contains a method to derive modeValue based on the logic you have above.  Doesn't get rid of it altogether but does make it more organized.

Comment: Shorter isn't always better. If the code works, is easy to understand and maintain then you should leave it as it is.

Comment: @Jonesopolis perhaps. But as-is, it's a bit out-of-context and very much **specific**. And **specific** questions are better off on [so]. [codereview.se] wants to know what your code does and why. Additional context (perhaps including the whole actual method) would allow reviewers to fully grasp what's going on, and make recommendations accordingly. Right now this is just "got a bunch of if statements, how can I make it shorter?" - which isn't exactly a *stellar* CR question.

Comment: @Nasreddine That was my initial feeling too. it's just that I thought I was perhaps overlooking a logical, neat solution with all the if...else statements

Comment: I'd recommend posting your actual code in its full glorious context over at [codereview.se], with a title that tells reviewers *what your code is doing* (i.e. **not** "shorten nested ifs"), and then walking readers through your code and the problem it's solving. I bet you'll like the answers you get.

Comment: @Mats Mug.  This is not a competition. I do not want to show other people how smart I am. This is an honest endeavor by a programmer who continuously wants to write better, readable, maintainable code. And in that endeavor it seeks the help of much smarter minds on this forum. Please try to understand that.

Comment: Yes, making code *better, more readable and maintainable* is **exactly** what the scope of Code Review is about.

Comment: You could also consider which is more important - the determination of "1F"/"2F"/"3F" and group those if's together or if mode-distance is more prevalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should replace the if-statements that deal with `mode` with a switch:

```
switch (mode) {
case 1:
    //...
    break;
case 2:
    //...
    break;
default: break;
}
```

Then you can replace the inner if-else chains with switches by placing them in a method (are these called "procedures" in C#?):

```
string Foo(int mode, int distance) {
    switch (mode) 
    { // http://stackoverflow.com/users/469563/gendoikari Thanks for pointing out redundant comparisons
    case 1:
        if (distance <= 4000)
        { return "1F"; }
        else if (distance <= 8000)
        { return "2F"; }
        else if (distance <= 12000)
        { return "3F"; }
        else
        { return "F 0-5"; }
    case 2:
        if (distance <= 500)
        { return ""; }
        else if (distance <= 4000)
        { return "2F"; }
        else if (distance <= 8000)
        { return "3F"; }
        else if (distance <= 12000)
        { return "4F"; }
        else 
        { return "F 0-5"; }
    default: break;
    }
```

Oh look, something awesome happened inadvertently! Now you can simply call `Foo` whenever you want to change `modeValue`!

```
modeValue = Foo(mode, distance);
```

Comment: Now this is exactly the kind of neat solution I was looking for! Thanks, dorukayhan!

Comment: That doesn't really compile though! (needs a default case with a return)

Comment: Oh... thanks for the warning

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

First off, you have redundant checks

`else if (distance > 500 && distance <= 4000)`

could simply be `else if (distance <= 4000)` instead, because of the "else" part.. you are already checking that distance is > 500 if you are in that else.

Second, it really depends on the context surrounding this, but this could be a good place to use multiple classes. I'm going to assume here that this is all inside a method called CalculateModeValue, and that method is inside a class called Calculator. I'm also going to assume that "Mode == 1" means "LongDistance", while "Mode == 2" means "ShortDistance".

In this case, I would have an abstract class called Calculator. I would then subclass this with 2 separate classes, "LongDistanceCalculator" and "ShortDistanceCalculator". CalculateModeValue would be an abstract method in Calculator, and implemented separately in each subclass. This way, you wouldn't need to check "If Mode == 1"; each class's implementation would handle the correct logic for that Mode.

But again, this is making assumptions on unknowns; it really depends on the context around these if statements.

Comment: *it really depends on the context around these if statements* - that.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using nested ifs the way you have them there.
But if you really don't want to look at them; Maybe simply input the logic in a method which takes in a mode variable and then proceeds to apply logic to the value of Mode?

Creating a sub procedure like this can also be re-used in your application to apply the same calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, I'd just make the if bodies one-liners without the brackets, that'll shorten it up real good. Your original code with some minor tweaks would look about as good as it can IMHO:

```
string Func1( int mode, double distance )
{
    if( mode == 1 )
    {
        if( distance <= 4000 )
            return "1F";
        else if( distance <= 8000 )
            return "2F";
        else if( distance <= 12000 )
            return "3F";
        else
            return "F 0-5";
    }
    else
    {
        if( distance <= 500 )
            return "";
        else if( distance <= 4000 )
            return "2F";
        else if( distance <= 8000 )
            return "3F";
        else if( distance <= 12000 )
            return "4F";
        else
            return "F 0-5";
    }
}
```

If you don't like that, there's a ton of ways of doing it. How about:

```
class Mode
{
    public double Distance;
    public string Name;
    public Mode( double d, string n ) { this.Distance = d; this.Name = n; }
}

string Func( int mode, double distance )
{
    Mode[] modes;
    if( mode == 1 )
        modes = new Mode[] { new Mode( 4000, "1F" ),
                             new Mode( 8000, "2F" ),
                             new Mode( 12000, "3F" ),
                             new Mode( double.MaxValue, "F 0-5" ) };
    else
        modes = new Mode[] { new Mode( 500, "" ),
                             new Mode( 4000, "2F" ),
                             new Mode( 8000, "3F" ),
                             new Mode( 12000, "4F" ),
                             new Mode( double.MaxValue, "F 0-5" ) };

    for( int pos = 0; ; pos++ )
        if( distance <= modes[pos].Distance )
            return modes[pos].Name;
}
```

Obviously you could reuse those arrays. Or you could have each mode carry a `Predicate<T>` or something like that that specifies the condition for that mode to be chosen. And I guess the `Mode` class could simply be a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` to shorten it some more.